# Apple SSL certificate for push notification x regular SSL certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ssl

I am implementing a push notification system for one of my apps, so I am following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) tutorial and generating a SSL certificate for that.

This app of mine involves also, some exchange of data between the app and the server and I would like it to be SSL protected and I was wondering of getting a SSL certificate from verisign or other company like that.

My question is: is this SSL certificate created for push a regular SSL certificate, so in that can use it also to establish a https connection to the server (and save a couple hundred dollars to order a third party certificate)? I don't know much about SSL certificates, but I hope it can be used for that...

This will be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each certificate is tied to a specific domain, I'm not sure how this would work.  There is a concept of wildcard certificates, but I still think they have to be for the same domain.

In your case, it sounds like you will have the Apple push certificate, which validates the connection between your server and Apple's push notification server.  The other certificate would be to validate/secure the connection between your iOS app and your server.  Both of these are assigned a different domain (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com vs. yourserver.com).

One option you do have depending on how your iOS app is structured is to use a self-signed certificate between your iOS app and your server.  I'm guessing the end-user will not be seeing the certificate anyway.  This might be a way to save you money before deciding on a third party certificate.

Comment: ahh, I see. Please explain this " self-signed certificate between your iOS app and your server." better. What is exactly this? Sorry by lack of knowledge about certificates.

Comment: @RubberDuck See http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html for an example.  A self-signed certificate is a certificate you create but is not validated by anyone (e.g. a CA authority like verisign).  It still does the intended purpose of being able to secure communication between the servers.  In your case, you might be exchanging passwords between your iOS app and server.  A certificate will secure that connection so that a hacker might be able to log communication between the servers, but it would be unreadable without the private keys.  Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks. If a self signed certificate protects the data why people pay to have a certificate from a CA authority?

Comment: Well, if this self-signed certificate is in a browser, then the browser will complain because it wasn't validated by a certificate authority.  A self-signed certificate is basically a certificate that has not been approved by a company such as verisign, etc.

Comment: @RubberDuck by the way, I am by no means an expert in certificates either.  :)